# How remove top extra space in some cells of table

Tags: html, html-table, space

I have a page that contains a table with one row and 3 colums.
All of content of my page, are in these colums. Means this table is like a framework for this page.
Right and left cells, have some pictures and links. Middle cell contain main text of page.
In middle colums, when I type my text, and when it goes long, in top of the right and left cells, extera space is created. if this text be longer, these spaces of top of the side cells, is greater.

Can anyone help me please how remove these space?

---

[Picture of problem link](http://upcity.ir/images/08045505971149328615.jpg)

Code:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td width="15%" align="center" style="background-color:#ffffff; margin-top: 0px;">
        <div style="margin-top: 0px">
            <b>
        <br class="style3" />
        </b>
        <br />
        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Solar Cell.jpg" 
            Width="140px" style="text-align: center" ImageAlign="Middle"/>

                </div>
    </td>
    <td width="70%" style="background-color:#ffffff; text-align: center; margin-top: 0px;">
    <div style="margin-top:0px"><asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        <p>
            <br />
            Original</p>
        <p>
            Text</p>
        <p>
            Will</p>
        <p>
            Be</p>
        <p>
            Here.</p>
        <p>
            <span id="result_box" class="short_text" lang="en"><span class="hps">Please</span>
            <span class="hps">note</span> <span class="hps">the</span> <span class="hps">
            space</span> <span class="hps">over</span> <span class="hps">the next</span>
            <span class="hps">two columns</span><span>.</span></span></p>
        <p>
            These spaces</p>
        <p>
            Will be shown</p>
        <p>
            If this text be long becuase of &lt;p&gt;&lt;/p&gt;</p>
        <p>
        </p>
        <p>
        </p>
        <p>
        </p>
        <p>
        </p>
        <p>
        </p>
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div></td>
    <td width="15%" style="background-color:#ffffff; margin-top: 0px;" align="center"><div>
        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="124px" 
            ImageUrl="~/Images/pic.jpg" 
            style="margin-top: 0px" Width="126px" />
        </div></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: are you working with html tables? if so, could you give the screen shot of your work?

Comment: I used html table in asp.net. I inserted link of picture of my problem and also code.